# What does Gmail app use to open the letter - fragment or activity? And how to achieve such kind of behaviour?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

1. What does gmail app open? a Fragment or an Activity?
2. How to override an animation of the DrawerArrowToggle that switches to the arrow and animation of changing the (?fragment/activity)  ?
3. If it is an activity - then how to substitute the support action  bar?
4. How the animation of translating the list item to the new (activity/fragment) works?

[image: Gmail app]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Most definitely shared element transition.

Comment: To achieve this you can open a new project and choose "Navigation Drawer Activity".